# How to allow access to my localhost wamp server outside my network?

Tags: android, mysql, localhost, wampserver

I have android project running on localhost wamp server

I want to show my progress to someone outside of my network

How do I let him test my project?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share your localhost IP (i.e. 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.0.1 etc.) with someone to access it from outside of your network. You will need to have a public IP address for that.

Check with your network provider if they have given you a static or public IP address. Then go to your router setting and add a port-forwarding rule so that any requests that comes to that specific port of your public IP address will be redirected to be processed by the server application that you are running in that port.

There are a lot of tutorials available online about setting up your public IP address based on the system (Windows, Linux etc.) that you are using.

The other way of doing that is to create a VPN access to your network and provide them the access of your VPN. So that they can connect to your VPN and then can access your local IP addresses.